# How to create color picker for website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to create color picker for website, similar to what Photoshop have?

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many great jquery plugins that can do that. I suggest yo have a look at [this](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-color-pickers-plugin/) site.
Without more specific information I'm not able to help more, sorry.

Comment: Thank you. Those plugins are what I was looking for. Just I have one question. Am I allowed to use it on website that have ads, because some of those jquery plugins have licence that says Noncommercial — You may not use this work for commercial purpose. That is the reason that I wanted to create my own color picker.

Comment: Jquery is an opensource product so you can use that on your commercial website for sure. Afaik you can use the plugins on your website unless it is is explicitly written that you have to buy them for usage. But in the list I posted a link to I did not find one you have to buy. Correct me if I'm wrong...

Comment: How to install jPicker, is there any documentation?

Answer (score 7):

HTML5 has introduced many new form elements, including an input with type of 'color'. In modern browsers, this pops open a color picker similar (but not exactly the same as) what Photoshop offers.

```
<input type="color" />
```

Here's the working draft: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.color.html#input.color

Answer (score 0):

You can find some plugins here:
http://jqueryui.pbworks.com/ColorPicker

Answer (score 0):

color picker using javascript

http://www.dematte.at/colorPicker/

with samples and code